# View cube bindTexture error when I loaded model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When I try to load model in the viewer the view cube, I get a warning:

> WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: bindTexture: object does not belong to this context".

[The screenshot of view cube without texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaAnX.png)

[Warning text in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nl4ys.jpg)

How can I deal with it or what mistake did I make?

As I have initialized several viewers in the page with different container `<div>` element, I'm not sure if that will cause a problem.

```
viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(container3D, config)
viewer.start()
viewer.setTheme('dark-theme')
bimViewer_3D = viewer
```

Comment: Please share more information such as the viewer version and environment to reproduce the error (browser and OS). Also let us know if this happens for a specific design or any design with this configuration